# Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am new in jQuery. I have used Datatables in grid.

I've hit an issue where jQuery data tables is showing in the info bar at the bottom:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndUfB.png)

I want to display first entries and page drop-downs,
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-condensed tableDesign tablePagination">
                            <thead>
                            <tr >
                                <th>File Name</th>
                                <th>TimeStamp</th>
                                <th>Total NON DND MSISDN COUNT</th>
                                <th>Total DND MSISDN COUNT</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>test1.csv</td>
                                <td>11/10/17 11:22:45</td>
                                <td>3
                                    <a class="downloadCampaign" href="">
                                        <u>Download </u>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>2  <a class="downloadCampaign" href="">
                                    <u>Download </u>
                                </a></td>
                                <td>Completed</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>abc.csv</td>
                                <td>12/10/17 11:22:45</td>
                                <td>3 <a class="downloadCampaign" href="">
                                    <u>Download </u>
                                </a></td>
                                <td>2 <a class="downloadCampaign" href="">
                                    <u>Download </u>
                                </a></td>
                                <td>Completed</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>xyz1.csv</td>
                                <td>13/10/17 11:22:45</td>
                                <td>3 <a class="downloadCampaign" href="">
                                    <u>Download </u>
                                </a> </td>
                                <td>2 <a class="downloadCampaign" href="">
                                    <u>Download </u>
                                </a></td>
                                <td>Completed</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>test2.csv</td>
                                <td>11/1/17 11:22:45</td>
                                <td>3  <a class="downloadCampaign" href="">
                                    <u>Download </u>
                                </a></td>
                                <td>2 <a class="downloadCampaign" href="">
                                    <u>Download </u>
                                </a></td>
                                <td>Completed</td>
                            </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var table = $('.tablePagination').DataTable({
       /* "sDom": '<"top"i>rt<"bottom"flp><"clear">',*/
        "bSort": false,
        "sDom": 'Rfrtlip',
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_",
            "sInfo": "View _START_ - _END_ of _TOTAL_",
            "sInfoEmpty": "No Entries"
        }

    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_paginate  {
    display: none;
}
.dataTables_length  {
    float: right !important;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Output: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Neo.png)

It's not coming side by side.

Comment: where you are using dataTables_length   class ?

Comment: It's out of the box class.No need to define in code.

Comment: Did you import the datatables JS and CSS files properly and in order ?

Comment: Where is html of "dataTables_length" class? float : right may causing this issue.

Comment: it seems your css is overriding some default css properties of grid

Comment: @YoYo yes. Updated above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello You can write css code below for data table

```
.dataTables_filter, .dataTables_paginate  {
  display: none;
}
.dataTables_length  {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.dataTables_info{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width:100px;
}
```

[To see demo jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dhaval_123/kbxwpL36/4/)

Comment: Thanks.But i want like **View 1-4 of 4** after this **Dropdown**, and both should align to right of screen

Comment: Need to help on adding background color for that line, You can see in the attached image in description. Thanks